# PLSQL 'IN' Operator

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I'm trying to select rows based on a range of 'dates' determined by the following PLSQL query, which currently delivers the results I need - being the 'date' object of the last 10 weeks of the day of the week when the script is run. Eg. running it on the 22th of May would yield, 15th May, 8th May and so on.

```
SELECT SYSDATE-(level*7) as DateRange
FROM DUAL
CONNECT BY LEVEL <=10
```

This generates a list of dates. Then I try and combine this with a parent select statement to get rows with the dates outputted by the above that are in the 'DAY' (of Oracle type DATE) column.

```
SELECT * FROM NEM_RM16
WHERE NEM_RM16.DAY IN (
  SELECT SYSDATE-(level*7) as DateRange
  FROM DUAL
  CONNECT BY LEVEL <=10);
```

Which gives no results, despite knowing that there are rows that have the dates generated by the above.

I've read that when using the 'IN' operator, values must be enclosed in single quotes, but I'm not sure about how to do this with the query above.

Am I going about this the right way by using the IN operator, or should I be doing a different type of nested query?

Comment: `sysdate` return date with time. Are you sure you want to select only those records in which the same time as the current? What do you have stored in NEM_RM16.DAY? Only date without time?

Comment: Your question is about the SQL `IN` operator and has nothing to do with PL/SQL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use `trunc` for truncate time component from `sysdate`

```
SELECT * FROM NEM_RM16
WHERE NEM_RM16.DAY IN (
  SELECT trunc(SYSDATE)-(level*7) as DateRange
  FROM DUAL
  CONNECT BY LEVEL <=10);
```

Comment: a `trunc(NEM_RM16.DAY)` might also be necessary depending on the values in that column

Comment: trunc(SYSDATE,'J') seems a bit unconventional. I'd go for trunc(SYSDATE) or trunc(SYSDATE,'D') myself.

Comment: `trunc(SYSDATE,'D')` truncate to start of week

Answer (score -1):

Maybe the format of the date returned by nested query does not match with the date format of the column NEM_RM16.DAY
Probably, if the dates are compared after making them of the same format, they will match properly

Like this

```
SELECT *
  FROM NEM_RM16
 WHERE TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(NEM_RM16.DAY, 'DD/MM/YYYY'), 'DD/MM/YYYY') IN
       (SELECT TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(SYSDATE - (level * 7), 'DD/MM/YYYY'),
                       'DD/MM/YYYY') as DateRange
          FROM DUAL
        CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 10);
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Dates (Date type)does not have format. A Date in varchar2 type must have a format.

Comment: the basic Idea here is right though; force the formats of both side of the date comparison to be the same.  If you need the time part of the datetime variable, remove the to_date and format mask from each side and convert each to a character string.

Comment: @Karl, I disagree - the basic idea is wrong, you don't format a date just for comparison, oracle can compare dates. If you want to ignore the time then trunc the dates as in turbanoff's answer

Comment: and if, as I said in my comment, you want to include the times e.g. if you want after 10:15 on the date in question?